# How to disable the triggers in SQL Server 2012 across session

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

Am running a SQL job in which am disabling the trigger on all the tables in a particular DB. But few triggers are getting enabled again thru' different script which runs from the application/web service. How can I ensure that triggers are not get enabled until the SQL job completes?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want one *session* to be immune from the trigger activity, rather than to disable the triggers (which will disable them for all sessions) whilst that session is running. If that's the case, and if re-writes are possible, I'd suggest using context info.

What you do is, within the session that should be immune, you set a particular context value, e.g.:

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x53494C4C59
```

Then, within your triggers, before doing anything else, check and exit:

```
IF CONTEXT_INFO() = 0x53494C4C59
BEGIN
    RETURN
END
```

Note that this is *not* suitable as a security measure - it relies on nobody, potentially maliciously, setting up their context info with the "magic, disable triggers" value in any other sessions where it's not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Damien!! Will try out this option. Is this context value represents anything? Or it's just a random number and I can use any number?

Comment: @RajeshBhat - you can use any number. I normally come up with some piece of text and then convert it to binary. E.g.`select CONVERT(varbinary(128),'SILLY')`  - but you'd probably want something more appropriate/distinctive.